# Are FPU/SSE/AVX registers not saved in core dumps?

Tags: linux, core-dump, gdb

While doing post-mortem debugging of my x86-64 application, I've come across a strange symptom:

```
(gdb) p/x $xmm1
$8 = {v4_float = {<unavailable>, <unavailable>, <unavailable>, <unavailable>}, v2_double = {<unavailable>, <unavailable>}, v16_int8 = {<unavailable> <repeats 16 times>}, v8_int16 = {<unavailable>, <unavailable>, 
    <unavailable>, <unavailable>, <unavailable>, <unavailable>, <unavailable>, <unavailable>}, v4_int32 = {<unavailable>, <unavailable>, <unavailable>, <unavailable>}, v2_int64 = {<unavailable>, <unavailable>}, 
  uint128 = <unavailable>}
```

Puzzled, I've then tried

```
(gdb) info all-registers
rax            0x7f4fb3286020   139980284911648
rbx            0x7fff90cbf720   140735622674208
rcx            0xffff0  1048560
rdx            0xffef0  1048304
rsi            0xfbeea0 16510624
rdi            0x7f4fb3386010   139980285960208
rbp            0x7fff90cbf6f0   0x7fff90cbf6f0
rsp            0x7fff90cad5e8   0x7fff90cad5e8
r8             0x7f4fb3386004   139980285960196
r9             0x4      4
r10            0x3      3
r11            0x246    582
r12            0xd466f0 13919984
r13            0xffff4  1048564
r14            0x7fff90cad620   140735622600224
r15            0x7fff90cad610   140735622600208
rip            0x7f4fc1c01728   0x7f4fc1c01728 <__memcpy_ssse3_back+7016>
eflags         0x10206  [ PF IF RF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
st0            *value not available*
st1            *value not available*
st2            *value not available*
st3            *value not available*
st4            *value not available*
st5            *value not available*
st6            *value not available*
st7            *value not available*
fctrl          *value not available*
fstat          *value not available*
ftag           *value not available*
fiseg          *value not available*
fioff          *value not available*
foseg          *value not available*
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
fooff          *value not available*
fop            *value not available*
mxcsr          *value not available*
ymm0           *value not available*
ymm1           *value not available*
ymm2           *value not available*
ymm3           *value not available*
ymm4           *value not available*
ymm5           *value not available*
ymm6           *value not available*
ymm7           *value not available*
ymm8           *value not available*
ymm9           *value not available*
ymm10          *value not available*
ymm11          *value not available*
ymm12          *value not available*
ymm13          *value not available*
ymm14          *value not available*
ymm15          *value not available*
```

I take it to mean that core dumps don't save FPU and SSE/AVX state. Is it true? Or could it be a bug in GDB? How can I check whether the core file itself contains the values for these registers?

GDB is `GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-64.el7`. The same thing appears on Kubuntu 14.04 with the same executable and its core file with GDB 7.11 compiled from sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be true that Linux doesn't save these registers for the crashed thread. I've tried

```
eu-readelf --notes myapp.core
```

and it only reported `PRSTATUS` and various signal-related info for the crash, but not `FPREGSET`. Amusingly, other threads do appear to have `FPREGSET` saved in the dump. So the file just lacks this info.

I've found an [LKML message](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/12/17/175) about this posted in 2014, but there doesn't seem to have been any reply. I assume this is just a kernel bug, not something optional and disabled on my system.